# Factor producing NA values during SVM in R

Tags: r, dataframe, svm

I was unable to find any answers from a relevant post to factor() call producing NA values. I am still learning R, sorry if you find this post as dumb.
On the first factor() call, 167 NA values are produced in the dataset. With upSample(), "Class" column is added to the dataset, that's what I read from the R documentation( by help("upSample") ). After this line of code, by str() I found out it has a similar trend like the "is_patient" column (predictor/class variable) and by sum(is.na()) it gave 832 NA values. Now definitely something is wrong.
I also got a warning on createDataPartition() call. I still moved forward in the hope of positivity. But I knew this was going to turn ugly, as expected on training SVM model it failed because of NA values. Here is the link to code, dataset, and images for errors:

https://github.com/JordanTheDodger/SVM-
Ps: The code is not long so I am putting in the post too:

```
library(readr)
library(party)
library(caret)
library(ggplot2)
library(pROC)

df <- read_csv(file.choose())
str(df)
head(df)
names(df)
df <- df[,-2]
sum(is.na(df))
df$alkphos[is.na(df$alkphos)] <- median(df$alkphos, na.rm = T)
mdf <- df
str(mdf$is_patient)
head(mdf)

#factor
mdf$is_patient <- factor(mdf$is_patient, levels = c(0,1))
str(mdf) #1st factor call 2 levels, 167 producing na values 
sum(is.na(mdf))
set.seed(1234)
mdf <- data.frame(mdf)
str(mdf) # 1st data.frame call, 2 levels
names(mdf)

#updsmpling
mdf <- upSample(x=mdf, mdf$is_patient) 
mdf <- mdf[sample(nrow(mdf)),]
names(mdf) # "Class" column is added
str(mdf)
sum(is.na(mdf)) #832 na values
mdf <- subset(mdf[c(1:10)])
sum(is.na(mdf))#416 NA values
data_part <- createDataPartition(y= mdf$is_patient, p=0.7, list=FALSE)

#spliting the dataset
training <- mdf[data_part,]
testing <- mdf[-data_part,]
str(training) 
sum(is.na(training)) #292 NA values
trainCtrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number = 10, repeats = 3)
set.seed(7777)

svmModel3 <- train(is_patient ~ ., data = training, method = "svmRadial",
                   trControl = trainCtrl, preProcess = c("center", "scale"),
                   tuneLength = 20) 
svmModel3

predictor <- predict(svmModel3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. By scrutinizing factor documentation, I need to convert a column with int datatype using as.interger() then perform factoring. Refer to below code snippet:

`is_patient <- df$is_patient
levels(is_patient)[is_patient]
is_patient = factor(is_patient)
as.numeric(is_patient)`